# Get latitude and longitude from possible Google My Business address

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently integrating Google Maps Javascript API. I would like for the user to be able to type an address and have a "google street view" map generated for him. Preferrably, this street view map should be looking "inside" the office building. Example:
I am searching for "Zar Restaurant & Bar, Rosenheimer Straße, Munich, Germany" in Google Maps (link: https://www.google.bg/maps/place/Zar+Restaurant+%26+Bar/@48.1141096,11.6115833,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x479ddf9443819fc1:0xb242780e5bdc5ce5!8m2!3d48.114106!4d11.613772?hl=en). One business is found, and if you click on the image in the side panel, you are shown a 3d-view inside the restaurant. 
Alternatively, if a Google organic search is made with the same keywords, the business listing is displayed on the right and there is a button saying "see inside" that gets you there. I would like to achieve such a 3d-view map (showing the inside view) embedded on the site, as shown here: http://www.zar-bar.de/galerie.php . I am sure that this can be easily achieved by embeding the iframe google generates for you, but i would like NOT to use this method.

Question: How to get the same 3d view inside the business through Google Maps Javascript API? 
I know that the same map can be displayed by the JS API when you enter the lat & lng. I managed to find the needed lat & lng from this tool of theirs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start. From here, i saw the lat & lng from the params in the iframe src just below the imag . Then i placed the coordinates in google maps js api and it worked. Working code:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function initialize() {
    var position = {lat: 48.1141, lng: 11.6138};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('someDiv'), {
            center: position,
            zoom: 14
    });
    var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('someDiv'), {
            position: position,
            pov: {
                    heading: 240,
                    pitch: 10
            }
    });
    map.setStreetView(panorama);
}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cdfnvrj0/3/.  This lead me to believe that i need to get the lat & lng from a an address.

What i have tried:

Requesting Google Maps geocode API to get lat & lng from an address with the following request URL: 
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Zar%20Restaurant%20Bar,%20Rosenheimer%20Stra%C3%9Fe,%20Munich,%20Germany%20&key=AIzaSyBLASrj4k7gOpG62kdBWwGrGyHnfM71FT4"
This API finds the address and returns some geolocation data, but when i place these coordinates in my google maps JS api, the displayed position is not exactly the same. It places me somewhere on the street, not a 3d view of the searched business. This leads me to believe that this API returns geolocation based on the address as it is, and not an address of a business, i.e does not work for businesses. So, how does one figure out if there is a Google My Business address corresponding to a given address (through an API), and if there is such a business, how can i find out if it has an "inside view", and how can i take it's lat&lng to place it on a map? Is this currently possible with Google APIs?

I would be very thankful of all feedback and suggestions. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The [geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) is for postal addresses.  To find a "place" (like "Zar Restaurant Bar"), use the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/)

Places API result for "Zar Restaurant Bar, Rosenheimer Straße, Munich, Germany":

Rosenheimer Str. 240, 81669 München, Germany (48.114106, 11.61377200000004)

Geocoder API result for "Zar Restaurant Bar, Rosenheimer Straße, Munich, Germany":

Rosenheimer Str., München, Germany (48.1232636, 11.602944500000035) ["GEOMETRIC_CENTER"/"partial_match"]